# all we have to go on is this -- I don't understand how "have to go on" is used in this sentence

Tags: grammar, comprehension

The audio version is [here](http://tindeck.com/listen/jzfm) (from a movie called [Open Grave (2013)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2071550/)):

> — Hey, who are you, man?
>   — I don't remember who I am.
>   — None of us do.
>   — Okay, we have no phone and no computer. There's no way to contact the authorities. **All we have to go on is this.**
>   — So we know our names. I'm Sharon!
>   — I... Michael.
>   — You've met Lukas.

I don't think I comprehend this well. I understand *all we have* just fine; it means something like *that's all we've got here*. But I don't know how to make proper sense of *to go on*.

Just dawned on me. Does that mean something like *all we have (all we've got) to continue figuring out who we are is this* (and then we throws a bunch of identification cards on the table, apparently the identification cards belong to them).

Comment: The full expression is "have to go on" - it means "all the information we possess upon which to make a decision/action". An alternate expression is "all we have to work with"

Comment: I'm not so sure if it's even an expression. I couldn't find anything about this expression on the net.

Comment: well, it's all we have to go on, so it'll just have to do :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To have/got X to go on* means "to know X currently / right now / at this moment" with it understood that the subject is missing full knowledge about a situation.

*All we have/got to go on is X* means X is all we know currently / right now / at this moment, and there's more we don't know.

Note that *have* in the above is pronounced with a "v" as in "victor" sound in the above.

If the "V" in *have* is pronounced with an "f" as in "foxtrot" sound, *have* changes meaning to *required*.

Thus - intransitively, the full phrase *have to go on* would then mean *required to continue / keep going* (*I can't stop here, I have to go on*). Transitively, it would mean *required to enter, begin, embark, or physically move on top of* (*I have to go on the plane now*.